# (Vue/Tailwindcss) I want to dynamically add tailwind styles to children with the help of computed function but it doesn't work as expected

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css

```
  <script setup lang="ts">
  import { computed } from 'vue'
  import type { Sizes, Colors as GlobalColors } from '@/types/global/global';
  import type {MainColors} from './types'

  const props = withDefaults(
    defineProps<{
      size?: Sizes
      color?: GlobalColors
      src?: string
      alt?: string
      width?: number
      height?: number
      text?: string
      status?: MainColors
    }>(),
    {
      size: 'large',
      color: 'primary',
    }
  )

  const sizes = computed(() => {
      if (props.size === 'tiny') {
        return ['h-4', 'w-4']
      }
      if (props.size === 'small') {
        return ['h-6', 'w-6']
      }
      if (props.size === 'medium') {
        return ['h-8', 'w-8']
      }
      if (props.size === 'big') {
        return ['h-10', 'w-10']
      }
      if (props.size === 'large') {
        return ['h-12', 'w-12']
      }
      if (props.size === 'huge') {
        return ['h-16', 'w-16']
      }
      if (props.size === 'gigantic') {
        return ['h-20', 'w-20']
      }
      else return ''
  })
</script>

<template>
  <div
  class="
  flex avatar-group [&>.avatar]:-mr-3"
  :class="`
  [&>.avatar]:${sizes[0]}
  [&>.avatar]:${sizes[1]}`">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

If I write this:

```
class="[&>.avatar]:w-12 [&>.avatar]:h-12"
```

Then it's working just fine.

But if I pass props like 'large' or 'big' or anything less then it's only showing in styles like this:

[image]

[image]

So as far as i understand, the styles are not uploading correctly but the weirdest thing is that two of the props are working correctly that are - 'huge', 'gigantic'. And I have no idea why..

Comment: Check [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) page it should give you an idea why

Comment: Thanks, Ihar Aliakseyenka, your advice solved my problems :)